# django model forms on same page reset each other

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am a newbie for django and I am using two django model forms on one page but if one of them is submitted, the data in the model of other forms is cleared.

Here is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import UserProfile
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField
import floppyforms as forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ImageThumbnailFileInput(forms.ClearableFileInput):
    template_name = 'floppyforms/image_thumbnail.html'

class PhoneNumberInput(forms.PhoneNumberInput):
    template_name = 'floppyforms/phonenumber.html'

class ProfilePictureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """This form will be used to edit profile picture of a user"""

    class Meta:
        """Meta data about profile model is declared here"""
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ["picture",]
        widgets = {
            'picture': ImageThumbnailFileInput,
        }

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """This form will be used to create and edit profile information of a user"""
    class Meta:
        """Meta data about profile model is declared here"""
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ["gender", "phone_number", "address"]
        widgets = {
            'picture': ImageThumbnailFileInput,
            'phone_number' : PhoneNumberInput,
        }
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
```

Here is my views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from .forms import ProfileForm, ProfilePictureForm
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User as ThisGuy
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from .models import UserProfile
    from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile


    def profilepage(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            #Only Open it for logged in users
            profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__exact=request.user.pk)
            picture = profile[0].picture
            phone_number = profile[0].phone_number
            address = profile[0].address
            gender = profile[0].gender
            form1 = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, initial={'phone_number': phone_number, 'address':address, 'gender': gender, 'first_name': request.user.first_name, 'last_name': request.user.last_name, 'email':request.user.email} )
            form2 =ProfilePictureForm(request.POST, request.FILES, initial={'picture':picture} )
            context = {
            "form1": form1,
            "form2": form2,
            # "title": "Edit your profile"
            }
        else:
            #Redirect to login page
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login/')
        if request.method=='POST' and 'ProfileForm' in request.POST:

            if form1.is_valid():
                instance = form1.save(commit = False)
                instance.user = request.user
                requestuser = request.user
                requestuser.first_name = form1.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
                requestuser.last_name = form1.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
                requestuser.email = form1.cleaned_data.get("email")
                requestuser.save()
                instance.save()
        elif request.method=='POST' and 'PictureForm' in request.POST:
            if form2.is_valid():
                instance2 = form2.save(commit = False)
                instance2.user = request.user
                if request.FILES.get('picture') is None:
                    instance2.picture = profile[0].picture
                else:
                    instance2.picture = request.FILES.get('picture')
                instance2.save()

        return render(request, "profile/edit.html", context)
```

Here is my template file:

```
<html>
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load crispy_forms_field %}
{# image_thumbnail.html #}
{% load i18n %}
{% block jumbotron %}
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Edit your profile here</h1>
        <form method="Post" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>{%csrf_token%}
            {{ form2|crispy }}
            <input type="submit" name = "PictureForm" value = "Save Picture"></input>
        </form>

        <form method="Post" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>{%csrf_token%}
            {{ form1|crispy }}
            <input type="submit" name = "ProfileForm" value = "Save Information"></input>
        </form>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but what's the question?

Comment: **form1** and **form2** should appear in one `<form ... > ` then you can get the whole data in **reuqest.POST**. Remember only submitted data can be  sent to server.